# how to avoid group by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

let's say i have a table with 2 col: title, url. Url is unique, title is not. 
I must select unique titles and any one of corresponding urls. 
Easiest way to use group by title, but I cannot do this because table is huge. 
Any way around?

Comment: if you're worried about the cost of the `group by` on a large table, I think that any other solution would be more costly. Unless you select everything and you filter in the programming language you're using

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a nasty workaround, because I'd do it with a `group by` clause, but here it goes:

```
select t1.title, t1.url
from table t1
where not exists (select * from table t2 where t2.title = t1.title and t2.url < t1.url)
```

Anyway, I still think you should try the query with a `group by` and use some index perhaps to speed up the query. A good indexed table should do it even with lots of data.

Comment: Thanks, but it takes even longer.

Comment: Unfortunately do not have rights to build a new index

Comment: I was thinking about something like this:<code>select distinct t1.title,
(
select a.url from table1 t2 where t1.url=t2.url AND t1.title=t2.title limit 1
)
from table1 t1;</code> but it does not work